# Проверка значения в ячейке таблицы на основе выборки из таблицы

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблицы юзеров и вопросов:

**Questions:**
Id
Question

**Variants:**
Id
QuestionId
Variant
IsTrue

**ResultsTable:**
Id
QuestionId
UserId
VariantId

Как сделать проверку, что б в поле VariantId  можно было внести Id только варианта,к которому принадлежит вариант ответа, а не любой из вопросов?

Пример:
Вопрос 1- Сколько будет 2+2?
Вариант id 1 =8; id 2=4
ResultsTable - Юзер 1 отвечает на вопрос 1 ответом id 2  (тоесть верно)
Вопрос 2-  Кто быстрее?
Вариант id 331 ="улитка"; id 332="Порше без колёс"
Без проверки на вопрос 1 можно ответить вариантом из вопроса 2, что не верно...

Comment: Если честно, ничего не поняла. Приведите примеры исходных данных и какой результат надо получить.

Comment: @"Ella Svetlaya" добавил

Comment: Вам надо перестраивать логику, не верно организована структура таблиц.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычные ограничения (check constraints) работать в Вашем случае не будут потому что при проверке корректности вставляемого значения одного атрибута Вам нужно просмотреть значения атрибутов другой таблицы. А чтобы выявить между ними связь нужен отдельный запрос. Но запросы вставлять в условия ограничений СУБД как правило не дают.

Можно написать триггер, который будет делать все нужные проверки (в нём-то сколько хочешь запросов можно выполнять), срабатывающий на вставку/изменение значений в таблице ResultsTable. Если значения не корректные, то выкидываем исключение. Но тут важно, чтобы Ваша БД поддерживала триггеры. SQL-Server, насколько я помню, поддерживает.

Ещё можно сделать уникальный индекс Variants(QuestionId, Id) и установить на него foreign key в ResultsTable (QuestionId,VariantId). Это более универсально.

Но прежде всего подумайте о структуре Вашей базы. Из каждой записи таблицы Variants можно достать QuestionID. То есть для каждой записи из ResultsTable итак доступен QuestionID (через Variants), а Вы туда ещё 1 QuestionID запихиваете. Причём он должен совпадать с QuestionID из Variants. Это уже дублирование данных. Иногда оно оправдано (например, из соображений производительности), но чаще всего только приносит проблемы с целостностью и увеличивает размер базы. Проще всего убрать QuestionID из ResultsTable и все проблемы будут решены. Правда, придётся переписывать запросы к базе из использующего её приложения.

Comment: @"Yury Plinto" как убрать QuestionID? А как же узнать тогда, на какой вопрос ответил юзер...и каким вариантом?

Comment: @"Rakzin Roman", Вы сами сказали, что Вам не нужна ситуация, когда юзер отвечает на вопрос вариантом из другого вопроса. Значит определить вопрос можно однозначно из таблицы Variants.  Просто в запросы к ResultsTable придётся добавить join (объединение) с Variants. Например, вместо SELECT UserID, QuestionID, VariantID FROM ResultsTable; станет SELECT rt.UserID, v.QuestionID, rt.VariantID FROM ResultsTable rt JOIN Variants v ON rt.VariantID = v.VariantID;

Comment: @"Rakzin Roman" Тем более это объединение в том или ином виде в некоторых Ваших запросах итак присутствует, я в этом уверен. Скажем, надо Вам узнать, правильный ли вариант выбрал юзер. Вы ведь тогда также объединяете в запросе ResultsTable и Variants. Конечно, дублирование QuestionID может сделать запросы к базе немного быстрее. Я не знаю, насколько критична производительность в Вашем проекте. Но если проблем с быстродействием нет и не предвидится, тогда убирайте эту денормализацию. Избавитесь от проблем с целостностью, а заодно размер базы уменьшите.

Answer (score 1):

Создать уникальный индекс Variants(QuestionId,Variant).

Создать индекс ResultsTable(QuestionId,VariantId).

Установить FK Constraint.

Comment: подскажите, что значит Установить FK Constraint.? Это ключ к чему?

Comment: Foreign key может указывать на primary key или на unique. У нас второй случай. Это должно позволить вставлять в ResultsTable только те сочетания QuestionId/VariantId, которые есть в таблице Variants.